# Asus A035PC video driver download

Tags: drivers

I am searching on Google for Asus A035PC video driver but without success. Can someone help me to find this driver?
It's Graphic Card on MSI KT3V motherboard.

**EDIT**

Hardware id listing:

PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4153&SUBSYS_00901043&REV_00
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4153&SUBSYS_00901043
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4153&CC_030000
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4153&CC_0300

Comment: Can you tell us what the hardware ID is? E.g. via lspci under Linux, or via the device manager in windows.

Comment: @Hennes, see update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vendor 1002 indicates ATI. (now bought by AMD).

PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4153 points to an `ATI Radeon 9550 X1050 Series`.

Searching on [AMD's website](http://support.amd.com/) I read that `The following products have been moved to the legacy software support structure` ... `ATI Radeon 9550 Series` ...

Thus you will need to download the **legacy AMD catalyst** driver for your OS.

Edit:

- Start at http://support.amd.com/US/Pages/AMDSupportHub.aspx
- In the upper right corner select 'Desktop graphics'
- Radeon 9xxx series
- Radeon 9550 series
- Windows XP - 32 bit

Press 'results' to take you to the download page for [this driver](http://www2.ati.com/drivers/10-2_legacy_xp32-64_dd_ccc.exe)

Comment: I am using Windows XP but can't find legacy catalyst driver for it. I've just found for Vista.

Comment: I think it is thing one: http://www2.ati.com/drivers/10-2_legacy_xp32-64_dd_ccc.exe

Comment: `Vendor 1002 indicates ATI`. How did you know it?

Comment: PCI ids are unique and publicly known. You can look them up at several websites (e.g. http://www.pcidatabase.com/ ).  Or you can just google on the IDs. The combination of those two often helped my to identify third party components and locate drivers for them.